# Specifying Postgres table schemas in Esqueleto/Persistent

Tags: postgresql, haskell, persistent, esqueleto

I'm using Esqueleto with Postgres and I don't see a way to specify the schema that a table resides in.  Currently I'm issuing the following sql to set the schemas:

```
set search_path to foo,bar;
```

This allows me to use the tables I want as long as they are in schema foo or schema bar.  Is there a way to just set the schema for each table?